# What is the difference between "schmeichelhaft" and "schmeichlerisch"?

Tags: difference, adjective

The words "schmeichelhaft" and "schmeichlerisch" seem to have the same meaning. Is there any difference in connotation between these words, e.g., contexts when you would use one and not the other?

Comment: *Schmeichlerisch*? Sounds ugly. I'd recommend to forget about this word. Try *schleimig* instead.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't consider them the same. A compliment is "schmeichelhaft" while "schmeichlerisch" is rather used adverbially, a little like "smooth-tongued" maybe. I don't think you can exchange the two words in the following sentences:

> Er machte ihr ein sehr schmeichelhaftes Kompliment.

and

> Mit schmeichlerischen Komplimenten wollte er sie überzeugen.

As for connotation, I would say that I feel there is a slightly negative one when "schmeichlerisch" is used, while "schmeichelhaft" is positive.

Comment: Positive/negativ ist immer eine persönliche Wertung und vom Kontext abhängig. Ohne dass man den Satz ändert kann eine Aktivität von positiver zu negativer Bewertung wechseln, wenn man Partei wird, und ohne Partei zu ergreifen gibt es keine Bewertung.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add another aspect to Anke's answer:

- To me, "**schmeichelhaft**" is more about *how the compliment is
  received* - **recipient's POV**, usually **positive**
- while  "**schmeichlerisch**" is more about *how the intention behind
  the compliment is perceived* - **giver' s POV**, usually
  **negative**.

It seems to me that there is a similar difference if you consider two instances of "flattering" (adj. vs. verb) in English:

- If a compliment or a dress are **flattering** (**adj.**), it's understood
  that this is a good thing.
- If a person is **flattering** (**verb**) someone, this has somewhat negative
  overtones of dishonesty, ulterior motives, etc.

EDIT: User unknown has alerted me to the fact that there apparently are people who do NOT associate positive/negative nuances with these two words - nevertheless, please be aware that most of us do and will automatically infer a certain degree of censure if you describe someone's behaviour as "schmeichlerisch".

Comment: Dann muss ich auch den Kommentar für Dich wiederholen. "Positiv" und "negativ" sind Wertungen, die gar nichts mit der Frage zu tun haben, und nur scheinbar irgendwie helfen.

Comment: Ich muss gestehen, dass ich der Parteien-Argumentation in Deinem Kommentar nicht so richtig folgen kann. Zum vorliegenden Kommentar: Es war doch ausdrücklich nach Konnotationen gefragt. Außerdem finde ich es schon ziemlich hilfreich, zu wissen, welchen Beigeschmack bestimmte Wendungen haben - oder hältst Du die beiden Ausdrücke für neutral, ohne jede Tendenz?

Comment: Ein Verhalten kann schmeichlerisch sein, und ich kann das gut finden oder nicht. Die Annahme, dass man das immer schlecht findet, ist ein Vorurteil.

Comment: Ach so, Du beziehst dich auf den reinen Sachverhalt, dass etwas nettes gesagt wurde. Mein Standpunkt ist eher der, dass in der Beschreibung meistens schon implizit eine Wertung enthalten ist, dass nämlich die meisten "schmeichlerisch" nur verwenden werden, um eine Schmeichelei zu beschreiben, die sie als nicht 100% positiv wahrnehmen. Was der Zuhörer davon hält, steht auf einem komplett anderen Blatt.

Comment: Ob Zuhörer oder Sprecher, Leser oder Schreiber ist egal. Ebenso egal ist, ob die meisten - also etwa 51% oder 75% oder 99% derer, die dem Wort begegnen, damit eine Wertung verbinden und ob das eine schlechte oder gute ist. Die Wertung ist nicht mit dem Begriff verbunden. Es gibt auch keine Alternativbegriffe, für Fälle, in denen man die Vorgänge begrüßt, weil dies überflüssig ist. Die Wertung gehört nicht zum Wort. Ich muss aber die bedauerliche, naive Fehleinschätzung immer wieder feststellen.

Comment: Ok, ich bin raus.

Answer (score 4):

*schmeichelhaft* attributes *what* it's being said, while *schmeichlerisch* attributes *how* something is being said/*how* a person is saying it.

So one attributes the message itself, while the other really attributes the messenger.

For example a compliment can be *schmeichelhaft*, while the person making the compliment would be *schmeichlerisch* in making the *schmeichelhaft* compliment.

Comment: Das ist doch m.E. der Punkt.